# React-select show date on selected

Tags: reactjs, react-select

[image]

I am using [react-select](https://github.com/jedwatson/react-select), i need to show date based on the selected value, following are the option i am using.

```
const dueOptions =  [
  {
    value : 1,
    label : "Today"
  },{
    value : 15,
    label : "After 15 days"
  },{
    value : 30,
    label : "After 30 days"
  },{
    value : 31,
    label : "Custom"
  }
];
```

Comment: i don't think you can do with the react-select you can check out lots of example of all here https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/    and for the date select you can use any date picker.

Comment: How about showing dates in bracket?

Comment: I would suggest putting the date outside the Select component somewhere

Comment: Thats exactly how React-Select v2 "date picker" works (experimental section). Just no need for calendar - https://react-select.com/advanced

Comment: Yes, i have seen it but its complicated to analyze, just i need to show date, can you provide some simple example as a hint, @juscode yes please provide some example

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it creating a state in component and using Moment js

```
state={
   selected_date:""
}
```

And then updating the state every time on change of react-select using a similar functionality like onChange

Here's the function

```
showDate = (selectedValue) => {
    var toDay = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
    var newDate = moment(toDay, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(selectedValue, 'days');
    this.setState({
        selectedDate:newDate
    });
}
```

Comment: I think yes according to their documentation just update there state `selected_option` by appending the date calculated from the function I have given. Link to documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select#installation-and-usage